# JavaScript dictionary syntax error when injecting array element as property name

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am running this code but it is giving the strange results?

```
let surveyTypes = [1,2];

let surveyDuration = {
  surveyTypes[0]:  'first',surveyTypes[1]:  'second' 
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
surveyDuration={1:'first',2:'second'}
```

**Actual Output:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: You may want to use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead. The keys of the map would be type save and ordered (object literal is not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to `wrap` the array's item into *brackets* because you're creating `dynamic` keys.

```js
let surveyTypes = [1,2];

let surveyDuration = {
  [surveyTypes[0]]:  'first',[surveyTypes[1]]:  'second' 
}

console.log(surveyDuration);
```

Comment: And that is if the browser's JS Engine supports this.

Comment: @epascarello, then we need to use a `transpiler`.

Comment: @Mihai  i know we can create dynamic keys by array notation but i,am wondering [surveyTypes [0]] this will return ["1"] and it works fine, why surveyTypes [0] is not working properly  ? will you please explain it

Comment: @Saurabh That's incorrect: `surveyTypes[0]` returns 1 and `surveyTypes[1]` returns 2 so it creates an object with properties named `1` and `2`, just like the expected output from the OP `surveyDuration={1:'first',2:'second'}`

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut   iam [surveyTypes[0]] this will return ["1"]  if iam correct ?

Comment: @Saurabh, yes, if you're using this statement but not as object key.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
let surveyTypes = [1,2];

let surveyDuration = {
  [surveyTypes[0]]: 'first',
  [surveyTypes[1]]: 'second' 
}
```

In order to evaluate the key name, it must be inside brackets. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

---

While `surveyTypes[0]` does indeed return `1`, the reason you cannot use it on its own asn an object key, is purely because the syntax for javascript does not allow it. This syntax choice was made to allow you to write plain keys, that don't conflict with expressions. For example:

```
const obj = {
  hello: 'there'
}
```

vs

```
const hello = 5
const obj = {
  hello: 'there'
}
```

Notice how these would be ambiguous without bracket notation.

Comment: please search before posting duplicate answers for a widely known issue.

Comment: the problem was that. I did not found any keyword related with this problem. When i search the error name. I shows me the different stack overflow question. Therefore i posted this question.

Comment: @Sunny My comment was not meant for you, it was for MattWay; with high rep, he should know better that this question has already been answered. In any case, the right name to search for is "computed property name in object initializers" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: @JuanMendes I read this question more of a 'why', than a 'how', and thought it deserved its own answer, I just hadn't completed it before it was marked as duplicate. Neither of the marked duplicates explain why in any of their answers.

Comment: @MattWay I guess what you explained was kind of obvious to me.